# using some condition to search target data then replace them with a sequence

Tags: sas

I'd like to search a column in a dataset based on some conditions. Then replace them with a sequence with range [0,1] and 1/n as increment (n is the number of data found based on the condition). For example, search odd numbers in column j in the Test dataset below. Then replace '3, 5, 7, 9, 11' with '0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.1'.

```
data test;
 do i=1 to 10 by 1;
 j=i+1;
 output;
 end;
run;
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A simple `retain` with a conditional increment would work...

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  retain condition_met . ;
  /* increment based on condition */
  if (mod(i,2) = 1) then do ; /* odd numbers */
    condition_met + 1 ;
    /* apply */
    value = 1 / condition_met ;
  end ;
run ;
```